# Use the private variable of the superclass with friend

Tags: c++, inheritance, private, friend

I have a class A with a private variable a. Class B is a subclass of A. In class B_Test, I would like to wrtite something like "B b; b.a;", I put friend class C in both Class A and Class B but it still no works.

Any idea? Thank you.

(Sorry I make a mistake in my code when I post this question. It is solved now). Rod_Algonquin is right. Thank you.)

Comment: you cant access a private variable using a friend

Comment: The private variable a is defined in A, B inherit A. Can I still use B.a with friend?

Comment: Is there a relation between `B_Test` and `C`?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Sure you can. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74d909f443247fa4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Private members do not get inherited*. If you want to access that member in the inherited class, you need to use `protected` modifier.

Comment: Thanks Andro. So it is different from Java? Let's say class A has a virtual public function to return a, in this case what will happen to class B?

Comment: @xieziban Class A will be a polymorphic class and class B can now be casted to Class A but class A cant be downcasted

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: I'm not certain that answered the right question